# How to disable Expect-continue handshake header in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, http-headers, spring-rest

How to disable Expect-continue handshake header in Spring? I looked up the documentation but couldn't find something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with the expect-continue handshake when using Tomcat.

Switching to Jetty solved the problem.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721438/2219787